# How to draw a single bounding box on each line ,crop the bounding box and save image in folder opencv python

Tags: python, json, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am using this repo to https://github.com/mindee/doctr for OCR
I get the inference on the following image.

[image: Input Image]

The following predicted image is shown below
[image: Predicted image]

```
import json

from doctr.io import DocumentFile

from doctr.models import ocr_predictor



model = ocr_predictor(pretrained=True)

# PDF

doc = DocumentFile.from_images("/content/passbook_82_0.jpeg")

# Analyze

result = model(doc)

# Export results in json

with open("/content/preds.json", "w") as f:

    json.dump(result.export(), f)
```

The following JSON file saved the coordinates and confidence value. Each word has a geometry that gives [[xmin, ymin], [xmax, ymax]] in relative coordinates format.

```
{"pages": [{"page_idx": 0, "dimensions": [294, 632], "orientation": {"value": null, "confidence": null}, "language": {"value": null, "confidence": null}, "blocks": [{"geometry": [[0.0341796875, 0.169921875], [0.9775390625, 0.8896484375]], "lines": [{"geometry": [[0.0341796875, 0.169921875], [0.9775390625, 0.8896484375]], "words": [{"value": "anrdla", "confidence": 0.2445085644721985, "geometry": [[0.11328125, 0.1708984375], [0.1923828125, 0.212890625]]}, {"value": "veedas", "confidence": 0.16714346408843994, "geometry": [[0.1845703125, 0.169921875], [0.2744140625, 0.2158203125]]}, {"value": "State", "confidence": 0.9990315437316895, "geometry": [[0.642578125, 0.1748046875], [0.6982421875, 0.2236328125]]}, {"value": "Bank", "confidence": 0.999847412109375, "geometry": [[0.6982421875, 0.1767578125], [0.7529296875, 0.2236328125]]}, {"value": "of", "confidence": 0.9996934533119202, "geometry": [[0.7548828125, 0.1796875], [0.783203125, 0.22265625]]}, {"value": "India", "confidence": 0.9772151708602905, "geometry": [[0.78125, 0.177734375], [0.8388671875, 0.2236328125]]}, {"value": "REGULAR", "confidence": 0.8577464818954468, "geometry": [[0.0380859375, 0.2744140625], [0.1318359375, 0.310546875]]}, {"value": "SAVINGS", "confidence": 0.994958758354187, "geometry": [[0.140625, 0.27734375], [0.2314453125, 0.310546875]]}, {"value": "BANK", "confidence": 0.9993945956230164, "geometry": [[0.240234375, 0.27734375], [0.296875, 0.3134765625]]}, {"value": "ACCOUNT", "confidence": 0.9985705018043518, "geometry": [[0.3056640625, 0.279296875], [0.39453125, 0.3125]]}, {"value": "DARANGAMELA", "confidence": 0.4595634639263153, "geometry": [[0.73046875, 0.283203125], [0.8720703125, 0.314453125]]}, {"value": "No", "confidence": 0.9307771921157837, "geometry": [[0.0869140625, 0.322265625], [0.1201171875, 0.3564453125]]}, {"value": "CIF", "confidence": 0.9934298992156982, "geometry": [[0.03515625, 0.3212890625], [0.083984375, 0.3583984375]]}, {"value": "88537466750", "confidence": 0.9332917332649231, "geometry": [[0.3037109375, 0.3232421875], [0.4443359375, 0.361328125]]}, {"value": "DARANGAMELA", "confidence": 0.5046369433403015, "geometry": [[0.7294921875, 0.328125], [0.87109375, 0.359375]]}, {"value": "-", "confidence": 0.9411769509315491, "geometry": [[0.1826171875, 0.361328125], [0.1923828125, 0.3740234375]]}, {"value": "Account", "confidence": 0.9907050728797913, "geometry": [[0.0390625, 0.3564453125], [0.130859375, 0.3896484375]]}, {"value": "No", "confidence": 0.9819487929344177, "geometry": [[0.138671875, 0.3544921875], [0.1796875, 0.390625]]}, {"value": "20306950151", "confidence": 0.23563283681869507, "geometry": [[0.3076171875, 0.35546875], [0.4404296875, 0.3876953125]]}, {"value": "Customer", "confidence": 0.9558802843093872, "geometry": [[0.0380859375, 0.38671875], [0.1435546875, 0.4189453125]]}, {"value": "Name:", "confidence": 0.9982724785804749, "geometry": [[0.15234375, 0.3876953125], [0.2177734375, 0.421875]]}, {"value": "RASHO", "confidence": 0.6698806285858154, "geometry": [[0.2783203125, 0.388671875], [0.3466796875, 0.4228515625]]}, {"value": "Ms.", "confidence": 0.9627761840820312, "geometry": [[0.2265625, 0.388671875], [0.2685546875, 0.423828125]]}, {"value": "MANDAL", "confidence": 0.998543381690979, "geometry": [[0.353515625, 0.3916015625], [0.4326171875, 0.4248046875]]}, {"value": "S/D/W/H/O:BISWAMITRA", "confidence": 0.8553118705749512, "geometry": [[0.04296875, 0.4755859375], [0.296875, 0.5126953125]]}, {"value": "MANDAL", "confidence": 0.9796141386032104, "geometry": [[0.3056640625, 0.4794921875], [0.3828125, 0.51171875]]}, {"value": "Address:VILL-", "confidence": 0.7488418221473694, "geometry": [[0.041015625, 0.517578125], [0.2041015625, 0.5517578125]]}, {"value": "-", "confidence": 0.9209287166595459, "geometry": [[0.21484375, 0.5244140625], [0.236328125, 0.5498046875]]}, {"value": "CHUCHUNGJULI", "confidence": 0.5298648476600647, "geometry": [[0.2841796875, 0.5244140625], [0.4267578125, 0.552734375]]}, {"value": "NO", "confidence": 0.9970822334289551, "geometry": [[0.2392578125, 0.51953125], [0.2724609375, 0.5546875]]}, {"value": "Phone:2:284238", "confidence": 0.8328949809074402, "geometry": [[0.7275390625, 0.5283203125], [0.8818359375, 0.5634765625]]}, {"value": "SIDDHINATHPUR", "confidence": 0.5255517959594727, "geometry": [[0.208984375, 0.5703125], [0.3681640625, 0.5986328125]]}, {"value": "P.0-", "confidence": 0.7063982486724854, "geometry": [[0.138671875, 0.5654296875], [0.19921875, 0.6044921875]]}, {"value": "TAMULPUR", "confidence": 0.992978572845459, "geometry": [[0.44140625, 0.5703125], [0.54296875, 0.6025390625]]}, {"value": "P.S-", "confidence": 0.9322847127914429, "geometry": [[0.3779296875, 0.568359375], [0.4345703125, 0.6044921875]]}, {"value": "Email:sbi.091470sb", "confidence": 0.41425037384033203, "geometry": [[0.7275390625, 0.5732421875], [0.9580078125, 0.611328125]]}, {"value": "DIST-", "confidence": 0.9592916369438171, "geometry": [[0.138671875, 0.61328125], [0.2109375, 0.650390625]]}, {"value": "BAKSA", "confidence": 0.9974198341369629, "geometry": [[0.2158203125, 0.61328125], [0.28515625, 0.650390625]]}, {"value": "ASSAM", "confidence": 0.9992387890815735, "geometry": [[0.2900390625, 0.61328125], [0.3603515625, 0.650390625]]}, {"value": "781360", "confidence": 0.9988314509391785, "geometry": [[0.3671875, 0.6123046875], [0.4453125, 0.6494140625]]}, {"value": "Branch", "confidence": 0.9992311596870422, "geometry": [[0.7255859375, 0.6201171875], [0.806640625, 0.6572265625]]}, {"value": "Code:91471", "confidence": 0.6900002956390381, "geometry": [[0.814453125, 0.6220703125], [0.939453125, 0.6611328125]]}, {"value": "Phone:", "confidence": 0.9992220997810364, "geometry": [[0.0390625, 0.65625], [0.1171875, 0.6943359375]]}, {"value": "Date", "confidence": 0.9955922961235046, "geometry": [[0.7236328125, 0.6630859375], [0.7822265625, 0.7021484375]]}, {"value": "of", "confidence": 0.9997377991676331, "geometry": [[0.787109375, 0.6630859375], [0.8212890625, 0.703125]]}, {"value": "Issue:30/06", "confidence": 0.8237747550010681, "geometry": [[0.8310546875, 0.66796875], [0.9716796875, 0.70703125]]}, {"value": "Email:", "confidence": 0.9961839914321899, "geometry": [[0.0380859375, 0.701171875], [0.115234375, 0.7392578125]]}, {"value": "40/06/2020", "confidence": 0.2974379360675812, "geometry": [[0.70703125, 0.6982421875], [0.8583984375, 0.7548828125]]}, {"value": "5529182", "confidence": 0.9492482542991638, "geometry": [[0.8798828125, 0.712890625], [0.9775390625, 0.75390625]]}, {"value": "D.0.B.", "confidence": 0.8802379369735718, "geometry": [[0.0380859375, 0.75], [0.1171875, 0.787109375]]}, {"value": "Minor):", "confidence": 0.9770660996437073, "geometry": [[0.177734375, 0.7451171875], [0.2705078125, 0.78515625]]}, {"value": "(If", "confidence": 0.4771254062652588, "geometry": [[0.1279296875, 0.7431640625], [0.173828125, 0.7880859375]]}, {"value": "IFSC:SBINOOO009147", "confidence": 0.5092097520828247, "geometry": [[0.7314453125, 0.7568359375], [0.93359375, 0.7919921875]]}, {"value": "MOP.:", "confidence": 0.9868963360786438, "geometry": [[0.0341796875, 0.7919921875], [0.103515625, 0.830078125]]}, {"value": "RIMLON1781002512", "confidence": 0.2585943341255188, "geometry": [[0.705078125, 0.798828125], [0.9072265625, 0.83984375]]}, {"value": "No.:0000000203836166", "confidence": 0.8759520649909973, "geometry": [[0.1669921875, 0.8408203125], [0.4189453125, 0.87890625]]}, {"value": "Nom.", "confidence": 0.9955904483795166, "geometry": [[0.0361328125, 0.84765625], [0.091796875, 0.8837890625]]}, {"value": "Reg.", "confidence": 0.9835382699966431, "geometry": [[0.0986328125, 0.8447265625], [0.1572265625, 0.8896484375]]}, {"value": "BranchoMana", "confidence": 0.3897829055786133, "geometry": [[0.6943359375, 0.8486328125], [0.7919921875, 0.8857421875]]}, {"value": "DATION", "confidence": 0.5874566435813904, "geometry": [[0.796875, 0.8515625], [0.8818359375, 0.888671875]]}]}], "artefacts": []}]}]}
```

I want to draw a bounding box on each line and save the crop line image in the folder using OpenCV. How can I do that?
as shown below.

[image: Image I want]

Comment: How can I do it in python? Basically, I am new to it, I was doing it for one week. but unsuccessful so far.

Comment: That's why i am facing that issue

Answer (score 0):

You could grab a random bounding box, select for example upper right corner and find all bounding boxes with their right upper corner within a set number of pixels. From this sub set of bounding boxes take the coordinate of the upper left most pixel to the lower right most pixel.

Remove the sub set from the original set of bounding boxes and repeat until set is empty.

Im sure there are smarter solutions but this should work if all document are as well formatted as this.

Good luck!

Pseudo code:

```
line_boxes = []
while items left in bounding_boxes:
    box = bounding_boxes.pop()
    line = []
    for other_box in bounding_boxes:
        if (other_box.upper_right_corner - box.upp_right_corner) < tolerance:
            line.append(other_box)
    
    line_boxes.append(line)

final_lines = []
for line in line_boxes:
    upper_right = get_upper_right_coordinate(line)
    lower_left = get_lower_left_coordinate(line)
    cropped_line = crop_box_from_original_image(upper_right, lower_left)
    final_lines.append(cropped_line)
```

Comment: don't get your point. How can I apply it using the above JSON file in python?

Comment: Added pseudo code to clarify what I meant. Use the coordinate of the bounding boxes to find boxes that are within some y-margin which would correspond to a line.

Comment: Still does not get it, what is the item left and other_box? The JSON file has bounding box values of words